# Java Canvas Draw Image from BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, file, canvas

I am currently working on my personal project. The idea is to import a picture and crop it into n-pieces of bufferedimage then draw them with random sequence to a java canvas. After that save the canvas to image file. Right now iam stuck at saving the canvas and i have searching for the solutions but none of them work. Here my save procedure.
Please help, thanks in advance

```
 private void save() {    
    int r = jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this);
    File file2 = null; 
    if(r == jFileChooser1.APPROVE_OPTION){
    file2 = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();

    Graphics g2d = canvas.getGraphics();    
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
    canvas.paint(g2);  
    g2.dispose();  
    g2d.dispose();
    try  
    {  
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", file2);  
    }  
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error saving");
    }
    }
}
```

Update :
Now i get it, after using paintComponents now i can save the picture. Thanks @madProgrammer

```
public class CaptureImage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

MyPanel canvas;
BufferedImage[] processedImage;


public CaptureImage(BufferedImage[] proc) {
    processedImage = proc;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });

}

private void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "
            + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Output Picture");
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                save();
                System.exit(0);//cierra aplicacion
            }
        });
    canvas = new MyPanel(processedImage);
    f.add(canvas);
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void save() {
    JFileChooser jFileChooser1 = new JFileChooser();
    int r = jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this);
    File file2 = null;
    if (r == jFileChooser1.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file2 = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        canvas.print(g2);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", file2);
            g2.dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error saving");
        }
    }
}
}


 class MyPanel extends JPanel {

private Image[] processedImage;

public MyPanel(Image[] processedImage) {
    this.processedImage = processedImage;

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });

}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 300);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int loopj = 10;
    int loopi = 10;
    int l = 0;
    int jPieces = 100;
    int[] r = new int[jPieces];
    int rand = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        rand = (int) (Math.random() * (r.length));
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(r, 0, r.length, rand) <= -1) {
            r[i] = rand;
        }
    }
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (int i = 0; i < loopi; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < loopj; j++) {
            g2d.drawImage(processedImage[r[l]], i * 30, j * 30, this);
            l++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What is `canvas` in your example? A quick shot: Try `canvas.print(g2);`....

Comment: i mean it always return black screen, i have try canvas.print still got black screen. I use java canvas not the android.graphis.canvas

Comment: What does the `paint` method of the canvas look like?

Comment: Here i use drawtoCanvas to call paint method. Thanks in advance.


private void drawtoCanvas(BufferedImage processedImage, int x, int y) {
        Graphics g2d = canvas.getGraphics();
        canvas.paint(g2d,processedImage,x,y);
        
    }

public void paint(Graphics g,BufferedImage g2, int x,int y)
  {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(g2,x,y,this);
    
  }

Comment: for the paint(graphics) method, i did not modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `getGraphics` and you certainly shouldn't be disposing of it.

Instead of using `paint`, which could include double buffering, you should try using `printAll`

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);  
Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
canvas.printAll(g2);  
g2.dispose();
```

See [`Component#printAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#printAll%28java.awt.Graphics%29) for more details.

You should also be using the size of the `canvas` to determine the size of the image.  The above example assumes that the `canvas` has already been sized appropriately...

Comment: now i get a gray image file (looks like the background of the canvas before i draw it). Yes i have determine the size of the canvas.

Comment: Then it sounds like your not painting to the canvas correctly. I would then assume you're using getGraphics() and painting directly the Graphics context...

Comment: my current paint method. Hope u can help me
public void paint(Graphics g,BufferedImage g2, int x,int y)
  {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(g2,x,y,this);
    
  }

Comment: You really should be overriding paintComponent and calling super.paintComponent before doing anything else. Perhaps you should provide a runnable example and update you question...

Comment: thanks for your advice, you are right. After a major modification, now i get it right. thanks.

Comment: Could someone please enlighten me as to why this would attract a downvote?  In what ways does it not answer the OPs question? Does it do it in an inappropriate manner? It'd be nice to know so I could correct it